# Проблема с чтением html файла. UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, парсер, кодировка, utf-8, readfile

Тренируюсь писать парсеры.

Получив данные по ссылке сохраняю в файл html.
Далее открываю файл, и ищу в нем по тегу необходимое.

При промежуточной попытке проверить через print, что нашлось, выдает ошибку:

```
File "D:\pythonProject\parsing1\dynamic_parsing\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    scrap_master

File "D:\pythonProject\parsing1\dynamic_parsing\main.py", line 14, in scrap_master
    file.write(req.text)

  File "D:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 16449: character maps to <undefined>
```

Код такой:

```
req = requests.get(url, headers=header)

with open('temp_index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(req.text)

with open('temp_index.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    source = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

all_product = soup.find_all('div', class_='x-product-card-description')
print(all_product)
```

Encoding при открытии файла пробовал убирать, как в примере по которому я иду, но не помогает.
В Pycharm стоит utf-8.
Прочел все ответы по данной теме. Во всех релевантных случаях не указывают кодировку или указывают неверно.
Что я упускаю?

UPD:
При попытке спарсить другой сайт, все работает при убранном encoding при открытии файла для чтения.
Тем не менее интересно, что не так при первой попытке?

Comment: Так не факт, что сайт выдаёт кодировку `utf-8`, он теоретически может и другие выдавать. Судя по вот этому https://unicode-table.com/en/20BD/ это `UTF-16BE`. Но вообще-то в `UTF-8` этот символ нормально должен сохраняться, я пробовал. Проблемы видимо будут если вы попытаетесь его сохранить в родной кодировке `Windows` - `cp1251`, либо будете выводить опять же на виндовую консоль. У вас ошибка вообще-то не соответствует тому, что вы пишете. Вы пишете, что проблема при печати, а в приведённой ошибке проблема при сохранении в файл в кодировке `cp1251`.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что вы нас обманываете и показанный в вопросе код не совпадает с реально запускаемым кодом

Comment: 2CrazyElf. Да, вы правы с тем, что проблема при сохранении, просто всплыла она у меня при попытке распечатать результат уже.

Comment: 2andreymal. Какой мне резон вас обманывать? Я хочу понять возможную проблему. В upd я добавил, что на другом сайте код сработал без проблем. Это меня еще больше заинтересовало.

Comment: Так на другом сайте может быть другая кодировка и другие символы в тексте. Разбираться нужно с тем сайтом, на котором проблема